# Python script for creating new users with corresponding MySQL database in Centos 7

Tags: python, mysql, scripting, centos, centos7

The purpose of my Python script is to quickly create a new database for every time I add a new customer on my server. Every customer has its own user account, database and privileges.

I'm using Centos 7 with the MySQL community server (not the default mariadb). I have the following code saved in the this directory

/opt/hostingscripts/createdb.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys #package to read parameters
import MySQLdb #communication to database

##
## Script to automatically provision a database, user and user rights
## usage: ./createdb.py <databasename> <username> <password>
##

response = raw_input("Creating database " + sys.argv[1] + " and user " + 
sys.argv[2] + " with password " + sys.argv[3] +" Is this ok? (y/n) ")

if response.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
   print("creating")
else:
   print("exiting")
```

I want the following actions using this script:

1. The script expects 3 parameters <Database name> <Customer> <Password>
   (I was thinking to use python for the parameters using the sys.argy array however I'm confused how this works.)
   --> a new SQL-user is created using <Customer> as the name and <Password> as that SQL-accounts password
2. The ability to connect to the database using my root account and password
3. The customer needs to have all privileges on his database
4. I also want to give my user some feedback upon the creation of their database and account
   ex.
      databaseX created
      userX created

Comment: Why not just use something like Puppet, Ansible, or Chef for this? It would be super easy.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks !